# Linux ports are blocked even when firewalld is disabled!

Tags: linux, mysql, firewalld

RHEL 7.4

I disabled the firewalld and also checked that SELINUX is disabled.

But still when I use telnet to check the ports, port 3307 refused the connection.

Even port 80 rejects the connection.

When I enable the firewalld I can successfully telnet to port 80.

Is there anything else blocking the ports?

NOTE: there is no firewall before the linux system.

Thanks

Comment: firewalld is a frontend to iptables, did you check iptables directly? `iptables -L`

Comment: Yes, I did and the output shows there are no roles in iptables.

Comment: and did you confirm the default policy for the INPUT and OUTPUT chains? `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)`. If the default policy is `DROP`, then it will need rules to know what to allow. Also, you have a mysql tag but mention port 3307, isn't the default port for MySQL 3306?

Comment: The default port for MySQL itself is 3306 but for replication it is 3307.

Comment: That`s interesting, when I disable firewalld I CAN NOT telnet to port 80! when I enable it I can telnet to port 80!
 So it look like when the firewall is disable all ports are blocked by default, that`s my understanding.

Comment: This may sound dumb but... are `httpd` and whatever uses MySQL Replication actually running and listening?

Answer (score -1):

## check if the port is open with the command netstat

netstat -nlpi

If the port is not open through the firewall, the port will be unreacheable

Comment: Maybe explain how, from the output of your command, I can determine "if the port is not open." - Thanks.